# Reading in a csv, getting System.FormatException error, but not sure why

Tags: c#, csv

I am new to C#, and I wrote a little test application to see if I understand how to read in a csv file.

I created a class to handle the data received, but **my code will not compile**: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`.

Code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fileName = @"C:\Sample.csv";
            var file = new FileInfo(fileName);
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                List<Company> comp = new List<Company>();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName)))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        var values = line.Split(',');


                        var companyobj = new Company()
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]),
                            CompanyCode = values[1]
                        };
                        comp.Add(companyobj);

                        foreach (Company c in comp)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(c.Id + " "+c.CompanyCode);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: please post the content of your csv file

Comment: Here are the contents:
ID,CompanyCode
1,1000
2,2000
3,3000
4,4444
5,55555
6,666666

Comment: Check your file. One of the lines doesn't have in the first column a text that can be converted to an integer (including blank lines at the end)

Comment: the `foreach` will write everything in the `comp` list every time you add something to it. Your using statement doesn't need to have a FileStream returned to it, just the path will do (`var reader = new StreamReader(fileName)`). use a try/catch for the addition of the data to your companyobj, to catch failures within this section, and a finally for closure.

Comment: @MUG4N that could cause his indexes to become inconsistent from line to line.

Comment: Use a breakpoint on the line var companyobj to see what is in values prior to entering the variable assignment portion of the code, this will give you a great head start to figuring it out.

Comment: Are you sure the code doesn't compile? Does the error occur when compiling, or does it occur when running the app?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening on the following line:

```
Id = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]),
```

Since `values[0]` is probably not a valid int. Possible causes could be

1. The value is a string which contains nonnumeric chars
2. The you are reading a line (most likely the last line) which is blank and the `.split`is returning a blank string and failing when trying to convert.

I would says #2 is your more likely culprit.

Comment: code doesn't compile, so unlikely that it has anything to do with the contents of the .csv file

Comment: This is definitly a runtime exception: System.FormatException occurs when attempting to convert a numeric string to a numeric data type.

Comment: When I take the column header row out of the csv, it works fine.